# Unique solutions ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$ x \frac{dx}{dt} -4t =0 $$

i) Show there are two distinct solutions to the above at $x(0)=0$

ii) Does it have a unique solution that satisfies $x(t_0)=0 $

So the first part I think I've solved, I solved the ODE as an IVP found the two solutions to the problem namely $x(t)=2\sqrt{t^2} $ and $x(t)=-2\sqrt{t^2}$ and we're good.

But could somebody shed some light on the second?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry.

Comment: What about $x\left(t\right)=\pm2\sqrt{t^{2}-t_{0}^{2}}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to part (ii) of your question is, no.  here $$ x = 2\sqrt{t^2-t_0^2} \text{ and  } x = -2\sqrt{t^2-t_0^2}, t_0 \neq 0  $$  are solutions of  $$x\frac{dx}{dt}  = 4t, \, x(t_0) = 0.$$

Comment: Clearly, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

In part i), your solutions are not quite correct.

Your solutions to the equation can be simplified to

$$x=2|t|, \quad x=-2|t|$$

However, note that in either solution $x$ is not differentiable at $t=0$, since the left-hand and the right-hand derivatives are not equal. (In other words, there is a corner at $t=0$.) Therefore we cannot say that either formula for $x$ is a solution at $x(0)=0$. The best we can say is that those functions are solutions to the equation at everywhere except $t=0$, those functions are continuous everywhere, and $x(0)=0$.

You can remove those problems by adjusting your solutions to

$$x=2t, \quad x=-2t$$

These then solve the problem as worded. A slightly different wording of the problem would allow your given solutions to also be valid.

Comment: you don't want the absolute value signs.

Comment: @abel: You are correct, thanks for the catch. I'll edit my answer appropriately.